# Clock program doesn't count

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm new OOP student, I wrote simple clock program on Xamarin studio with C#. The format of clock is 00:00:00. It should be count up and work as a clock.
However, there must be some problems thus my clock can be draw on screen but doesn't "tick".

```
 using SwinGameSDK;
namespace MyGame
{
    public class Clock 
    {
        private Counter counter = new Counter();
        private int _seconds;
        private int _minutes;
        private int _hours;

        public Clock ()
        {
            _seconds = counter.SecondsCounter;
            _minutes = counter.MinutesCounter;
            _hours = counter.HoursCounter;
        }

        public int Seconds {
            get {
                return _seconds;
            }

            set {
                _seconds = value;
            }
        }

        public int Minutes {
            get {
                return _minutes;
            }

            set {
                _minutes = value;
            }
        }

        public int Hours {
            get {
                return _hours;
            }

            set {
                _hours = value;
            }
        }

        public void DrawClock ()
        {
            DrawHours ();
            SwinGame.DrawText (":", Color.Black, "Arial", 80, 360, 200);
            DrawMinutes ();
            SwinGame.DrawText (":", Color.Black, "Arial", 80, 520, 200);
            DrawSeconds ();
        }

        public void DrawHours ()
        {
            SwinGame.DrawText (Hours.ToString ("D2"), Color.Black, "Arial", 80, 250, 208);
        }

        public void DrawMinutes ()
        {
            SwinGame.DrawText (Minutes.ToString ("D2"), Color.Black, "Arial", 80, 410, 208);
        }

        public void DrawSeconds ()
        {
            SwinGame.DrawText (Seconds.ToString ("D2"), Color.Black, "Arial", 80, 560, 208);
        }

        public void UpdateClock ()
        {
            counter.UpdateCounter ();

        }

        public void ResetClock ()
        {
            counter.Reset ();

        }

        public void SetClock ()
        {
            counter.SetTimer ();
        }
    }
}


using System.Timers;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class Counter
    {
        private int _hoursCounter;
        private int _minutesCounter;
        private int _secondsCounter;

        public Counter ()
        {
            _hoursCounter = 0;
            _minutesCounter = 0;
            _secondsCounter = 0;
        }

        public int HoursCounter {
            get {
                return _hoursCounter;
            }
            set {
                _hoursCounter = value;
            }
        }

        public int MinutesCounter {
            get {
                return _minutesCounter;
            }
            set {
                _minutesCounter = value;
            }
        }

        public int SecondsCounter {
            get {
                return _secondsCounter;
            }
            set {
                _secondsCounter = value;
            }
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer ();

        public void SetTimer ()
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => UpdateCounter ();
        }

        public void UpdateCounter ()
        {   
            timer.Start ();
            SecondsCounter += 1;
            if (SecondsCounter == 60) {
                SecondsCounter = 0;
                MinutesCounter += 1;
            }
            if (MinutesCounter == 60) {
                MinutesCounter = 0;
                HoursCounter += 1;
            }
            if (HoursCounter == 24) {
                HoursCounter = 0;
                MinutesCounter = 0;
                SecondsCounter = 0;
            }
        }



        public void Reset ()
        {
            HoursCounter = 0;
            MinutesCounter = 0;
            SecondsCounter = 0;
            timer.Close ();
        }
    }
}

using SwinGameSDK;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class GameMain
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            var myClock = new Clock ();

            //Open the game window
            SwinGame.OpenGraphicsWindow ("GameMain", 800, 600);
            SwinGame.ShowSwinGameSplashScreen ();

            //Run the game loop
            while (false == SwinGame.WindowCloseRequested ()) {
                //Fetch the next batch of UI interaction
                SwinGame.ProcessEvents ();

                //Clear the screen and draw the framerate
                SwinGame.ClearScreen (Color.White);
                SwinGame.DrawFramerate (0, 0);

                myClock.DrawClock ();
                myClock.SetClock ();
                if (SwinGame.MouseClicked (MouseButton.LeftButton)) {
                    myClock.UpdateClock ();
                }
                if (SwinGame.MouseClicked (MouseButton.RightButton)) {
                    myClock.ResetClock ();
                }

                //Draw onto the screen
                SwinGame.RefreshScreen (60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side Note: Use Auto-Implemented Properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Is it even entering the method that should update the screen when tick happens?

Comment: First of all, you should debug your code to see what is happening. Maybe adding `timer.Enabled=true` in `SetTimer` make it work?

Comment: Side note - no need to put a space between the method name and the brackets... and the curly brackets should be in a new line in C#. I know it's not answering but the code is messing with my brain

Comment: waht i mean doesn't work is it doesn't count at all

Comment: You never enable the clock, and you reset it during every loop. Instead of creating a Clock class, you could use a couple of DateTime and then calculate the difference between them

Comment: Have you tried what i told you in my comment?

Comment: That's just a big wall of text which nobody here is going to debug. Please learn how to write a [mcve].

Comment: @Pikoh yes, it still doesn't count.

Comment: Then you'll need to debug it. What you should do in the first place is putting a breakpoint in your `UpdateCounter` method to see if the timer is really enabled and running...depending on that you'll see what to do next

Comment: @Pikoh I tried to debugged, it seems like it breaks at myClock.SetClock() which in Main()

Comment: Try to add `timer = new Timer();`as the first sentence in your `SetTimer`method

Comment: @Pikoh sorry it's breaks at UpdateClock

Comment: What does "it breaks" mean? Does it give you an exception? If it does, edit your question and add the exception error message.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your clock is not ticking **because you are continuously resetting it's interval using myClock.SetClock() method.** This method should be only called only once outside the while loop in main method. Try following main method;

```
    public static void Main ()
    {
        var myClock = new Clock ();

        //Open the game window
        SwinGame.OpenGraphicsWindow ("GameMain", 800, 600);
        SwinGame.ShowSwinGameSplashScreen ();

        myClock.SetClock ();                  //Set clock should be called from here.
        //Run the game loop
        while (false == SwinGame.WindowCloseRequested ()) {
            //Fetch the next batch of UI interaction
            SwinGame.ProcessEvents ();

            //Clear the screen and draw the framerate
            SwinGame.ClearScreen (Color.White);
            SwinGame.DrawFramerate (0, 0);

            myClock.DrawClock ();

            if (SwinGame.MouseClicked (MouseButton.LeftButton)) {
                myClock.UpdateClock ();
            }
            if (SwinGame.MouseClicked (MouseButton.RightButton)) {
                myClock.ResetClock ();
            }

            //Draw onto the screen
            SwinGame.RefreshScreen (60);
        }
    }
```

And SetTimer should be as follows

```
    public void SetTimer ()
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => UpdateCounter ();
        timer.Start ();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your method but it still not work.. and I want to let user choose to start clock so i put timer.start in UpdateCounter()

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you dont even start the timer.
instead of calling **timer.Start ();** in **UpdateCounter ()**, start the timer after **timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => UpdateCounter ();**.

you should also keep your variables together.

```
private int _hoursCounter;  
private int _minutesCounter;  
private int _secondsCounter;  
Timer timer;
```

and initialize the timer in the constructor:

```
..
_secondsCounter = 0;
timer = new Timer();
```

Comment: you should provide more infor on what does not work, put breakpoints on variables and construction methods and press f10 to see what is changing and what not. obviously you are missing something.